# Code not working

Tags: android, string, button, arraylist

My app has a list of questions.When the functoion getfirstquestion is called,it randomly choses a question,and after that it randomly puts texts on each of the 4 buttons(one of them is the answer to the question).

Everytime a button is pressed,the function checkanswer verifies if the button text equals with the right answer to the right question.If it does,it removes the current question,and calls the getfirstquestion() function to change the question.

The program runs ok,however nothing happens when I press the correct answer button.Can anyone tell me why,and give me a solution? I'm searching the code since 2 hours ago....

```
    public class startgame extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

final Random rgenerator = new Random();

List<String> questionss1 = new ArrayList<String>();
String thequestion;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level1);

    questionss1.add("Who is the actual CEO at Apple?");
    questionss1.add("Who is the actual CEO at Microsoft?");
    questionss1.add("Who is the actual CEO at Google?");
    getfirstquestion();

    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    }

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:  

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        checkanswer((String) button1.getText());

    case R.id.button2:
       Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
           checkanswer((String) button2.getText());

    case R.id.button3:
        Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    checkanswer((String) button3.getText());

    case R.id.button4:
        Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
       checkanswer((String) button4.getText());
    }
}
public int checkanswer(String buttontext) {
    if (thequestion.equals("Who is the actual CEO at Apple?") && buttontext == "Tim Cook"){
        questionss1.remove("Who is the actual CEO at Apple?");
        getfirstquestion();
    }

    if (thequestion.equals("Who is the actual CEO at Microsoft?") && buttontext  == "Steve Ballmer"){
        questionss1.remove("Who is the actual CEO at Microsoft?");
        getfirstquestion();
    }

    if (thequestion.equals("Who is the actual CEO at Google?") && buttontext == "Eric Schmidt"){
        questionss1.remove("Who is the actual CEO at Google?");
        getfirstquestion();
    }
    return 0;
}

public void getfirstquestion(){
    //create the buttons
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    thequestion = questionss1.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questionss1.size()));
    TextView question = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    question.setText(thequestion);
    questionss1.remove(thequestion);

    if (thequestion.equals("Who is the actual CEO at Apple?")){
        List<String> questions1res = new ArrayList<String>();
        questions1res.add("Eric Schmidt");
        questions1res.add("Steven Sinofsky");
        questions1res.add("Tim Cook");
        questions1res.add("Steve Ballmer");

        button1.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button1.getText());
        button2.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button2.getText());
        button3.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button3.getText());
        button4.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button4.getText());
    }

    if (thequestion.equals("Who is the actual CEO at Microsoft?")){
        List<String> questions1res = new ArrayList<String>();
        questions1res.add("Eric Schmidt");
        questions1res.add("Steven Sinofsky");
        questions1res.add("Tim Cook");
        questions1res.add("Steve Ballmer");

        button1.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button1.getText());
        button2.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button2.getText());
        button3.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button3.getText());
        button4.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button4.getText());
    }

    if (thequestion.equals("Who is the actual CEO at Google?")){
        List<String> questions1res = new ArrayList<String>();
        questions1res.add("Eric Schmidt");
        questions1res.add("Steven Sinofsky");
        questions1res.add("Tim Cook");
        questions1res.add("Steve Ballmer");

        button1.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button1.getText());
        button2.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button2.getText());
        button3.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button3.getText());
        button4.setText(questions1res.get(rgenerator.nextInt(questions1res.size())));
        questions1res.remove(button4.getText());
    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button1.setOnClickListener(this);

This code is used to set an OnClickListener to a button.  You need to instantiate an OnClickListener in your class and use that.  Passing in (this) will pass in the activity.  The button clicks will do nothing in this case.

Something like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do your checking here
    }
};
```

Try that, let me know how it works.

Comment: He uses the activity as the OnClickListener, which is OK.

Comment: @user1015311 - if it solved your problem, great. I just want you to know, that although I prefer the method of Pheonixblade9, which is cleaner than using the Activity as a listener, using the Activity as a listener is valid as well, and used by most people.

Comment: @MByD I didn't even know you could use the activity as the OnClickListener! Haha.  But it seems like much better style to have dedicated listeners for each button, as long as it doesn't get any higher than 4.  Otherwise I'd suggest an OnTouchListener measuring the point he touched :)

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 - Well I agree that the listener should not be the Activity as a coding style, but I think that using one listener and appropriate lists is much better approach than listener to each button.

Comment: @MByD Personally, I'd create one listener and set all of the buttons to it.  Then check for the right answer :)

Answer (score 3):

In the method `checkanswer` you should use the `equals` method, not `==` operator, as it compares references and not content of object. i.e. instead of `buttontext == "Tim Cook"` it should be `buttontext.equals("Tim Cook")` etc.

Also, looking at your code again, you should addd `break;` statements in the switch:

```
switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.button1:
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    checkanswer((String) button1.getText());
    break;
case R.id.button2:
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    checkanswer((String) button2.getText());
    break;
case R.id.button3:
    Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    checkanswer((String) button3.getText());
    break;
case R.id.button4:
    Button button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    checkanswer((String) button4.getText());
    break;
}
```

Comment: now it worked,but it stoped after the first question.(the buttons just don't respond)

Comment: because I copied some codes,I forgot to change the buttons's number(ex on button 3 was number 2) and so on.However,your code worked great thanks!